# Colloborationgroup-visibility-testclass execution

Tags: apex, chatter, unit-test

Is colloboration group,an object whose records are always visible even when testclass is executed.
When i try to insert,say 95 records for chatter groups via testclass,it gave an exception saying maximum limit.(probably it has visibility to existing chattergroups data)

Rephrasing question:
In my org i have around 90 chattergroups created by me and 
I have below testclass .when i run this class it gives me an exception

```
Error Message   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Maximum per user collaboration group limit reached.: []

@istest
    public class ttest{
   static testMethod void searchbet()
    {
     list<collaborationgroup> cglist = new list<collaborationgroup>();
    for(integer i = 0;i<50;i++)
    {
    collaborationgroup c = new collaborationgroup(name ='test'+i,CollaborationType='Public');
    cglist.add(c);

    }
    insert (cglist);
    }

    }
```

Comment: can you post your test class here that you are trying?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: i have added more details above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not that collaborationgroups are visible per se, but the real groups do impact unit tests even if the test does not have the @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation.  If you try to pull the groups back via SOQL, you won't get any results, but there is still an impact on other actions you might take.

For example, there is a unique constraint on the name field and when you insert a new collaborationgroup via a unit test, the uniqueness constraint has visibility of the real data and enforces it.  This is documented (though its not overly clear) at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm

There's no mention of the real groups being taken into account when enforcing limits, but that is the behaviour that I see and I've put that down to the same reason as the above; that the limit (this one at least!) is enforced at a very low level and the test context doesn't influence that.  I haven't investigated this for any other sobject types, so I don't know if this is common behaviour or something specific to the collaborationgroup sobject.